# How can I delete those table rows (DataFrame) - by selection condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I delete those table rows (DataFrame) - by selection condition (whose value is > 3 (for example))

I'm trying to do it in different ways, I've also tried using loops - sorting through the desired column, and through operational commands Pandas

Something I can't do anything.
There is no change, no deletion, or an infinite loop.

I would really appreciate any help.

Thank you.

The table (DataFrame) shown below has 207000 rows, but after iterating through the condition and then deleting the desired rows, there are about 100000 rows.

```
Qnv = 8

lens = len(df_calc_rulet_q.index)


df_calc_rulet_q = df_calc_rulet_q.drop(df_calc_rulet_q[df_calc_rulet_q['summ']<Qnv].index)

# k = 1
# i = 0
# for k in range(lens):
#     if df_calc_rulet_q.at[i, 'summ'] < Qnv:
#         # print(df_calc_rulet_q.loc[i, 'summ'])
#         df_calc_rulet_q.drop(i)
#         df_calc_rulet_q = df_calc_rulet_q.reset_index(drop=True)
#     else:
#         i = i + 1

print(df_calc_rulet_q)

        Qvir1  Qvir2  Qvir3  Qvir4  Qvir5   summ
8         0.9   2.10    0.9   1.60    2.8   8.30
9         1.0   2.35    1.0   1.67    3.1   9.12
10        1.1   2.60    1.1   1.80    3.4  10.00
21        1.0   2.10    1.0   1.40    3.1   8.60
22        1.1   2.35    1.1   1.60    3.4   9.55
...       ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...
207608    0.9   2.85    0.9   0.60    2.8   8.05
207621    1.0   2.85    1.0   0.40    3.1   8.35
207631    0.8   2.10    0.8   2.00    2.5   8.20
207632    0.9   2.35    0.9   2.20    2.8   9.15
207634    1.1   2.85    1.1   0.20    3.4   8.65
```

Comment: Can't you select those with the conditions you want? Like get `whose value is <= 3`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100, size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
#     A   B   C   D
# 0  66  31  65  89
# 1  34  33  24  53
# 2   5  67  29  54
# 3  68  26  31  36
# 4   3  94   9  51
# 5  62  45  60  24
# 6  60  86  33  86
# 7  65  23  62  70
# 8  12   8  21  41
# 9  49  55  78  23


df = df.loc[(df['A']>20) & (df['B']<50) & (df['C']>60)]

#    A   B   C   D
#0  66  31  65  89
#7  65  23  62  70
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider [**`DataFrame.query`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) to filter rows you intend to keep and not [`DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) which is really intended to drop index or column labels not rows by conditions.

```py
Qnv = 8

df_calc_rulet_q_subset = (
    df_calc_rulet_q.query("summ >= @Qnv")
        .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```